# How to cache DNS TXT lookups with dnsmasq

Tags: domain-name-system, cache, dnsmasq, txt-record

We use `dnsmasq` on our Debian servers to cache DNS queries. This works find for A and CNAME queries. However, I notice that `dnsmasq` does not cache TXT queries. You can see this here:

```
2018-07-23T08:18:18.715485-07:00 kdc-uat2 dnsmasq[24645]: forwarded _kerberos.winuatdc1.winuat.example.com to 10.10.1.234
2018-07-23T08:18:18.716249-07:00 kdc-uat2 dnsmasq[24645]: query[TXT] _kerberos.winuatdc1.winuat.example.com from 127.0.0.1
2018-07-23T08:18:18.716307-07:00 kdc-uat2 dnsmasq[24645]: forwarded _kerberos.winuatdc1.winuat.example.com to 10.10.1.234
2018-07-23T08:18:18.717045-07:00 kdc-uat2 dnsmasq[24645]: query[TXT] _kerberos.winuatdc1.winuat.example.com from 127.0.0.1
2018-07-23T08:18:18.717103-07:00 kdc-uat2 dnsmasq[24645]: forwarded _kerberos.winuatdc1.winuat.example.com to 10.10.1.234
2018-07-23T08:18:18.717738-07:00 kdc-uat2 dnsmasq[24645]: query[TXT] _kerberos.winuatdc1.winuat.example.com from 127.0.0.1
2018-07-23T08:18:18.717767-07:00 kdc-uat2 dnsmasq[24645]: forwarded _kerberos.winuatdc1.winuat.example.com to 10.10.1.234
```

In the above log, there were three queries in quick succession to the same record, but `dnsmasq` did not cache any of them.

How can I get `dnsmasq` to cache TXT record queries?

Note: I realize that `dnsmasq` can deliver TXT records itself, but I do not want to do that because if I did and the people controlling the TXT record changed the mapping without letting me know, my record would be wrong and things would break.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think dnsmasq provides caching of TXT records. From the [home page](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html):

> The DNS subsystem provides a local DNS server for the network, with forwarding of all query types to upstream recursive DNS servers and caching of common record types (A, AAAA, CNAME and PTR, also DNSKEY and DS when DNSSEC is enabled)